# How to setup Google Compute Engine to work with websocket using subscriptions-transport-ws

Tags: google-compute-engine, graphql-subscriptions

Am using google compute engine with $300 credit, i have successfully deployed my APIs, the mutation, query are all working but the subscription seems not to be working. I used "subscriptions-transport-ws" library from apollo team, my questions are;

1. Does Google $300 credit support websockets or i have to upgrade from $300 before i the websocket will work?
2. If it support, how do i setup the VM to support subscriptions using this library subscriptions-transport-ws from apollo team

Comment: As far as I know there is no limitation for using websockets for Google Cloud trial accounts.

For your second question, what issues did you find?  What is not working? I guess you are using Google PubSub?

Comment: Am not using Google PubSub, pubsub.publish(NEW_POST, {[NEW_POST]: new_post});  and subscribe: withFilter(() => pubsub.asyncIterator(NEW_POST), (payload, variables ) => {return Boolean (payload.new_post.department === variables.department) })